# How to prevent Orchard projections from firing hundreds of queries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have the following problem with the Projections module in Orchard:
I have pages with main categories that when opened query a database (not the Orchard one, coming from a separate application) for it's subcategories and the items in those subcategories.

I have a projection that shows the main category titles in a widget for easy navigation. The page load times however skyrocket because even in the projection it tries to load each main category as a whole resulting in an exponential amount of queries against our second database and loading times in excess of 30 seconds.

Is it possible for the Projections module to only query for the Title Part (and perhaps any custom bindings) and ignore the part that executes those queries?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

We used the Mini Profiler and this is the result:
[image: mini-profiler output]

It seems that the problem is in the Display method of Orchard.Projections.Drivers.ProjectionPartDriver on line 111:

```
var contentItems = _projectionManager.GetContentItems(query.Id, pager.GetStartIndex() +     part.Record.Skip, pager.PageSize).ToList();
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this N+1 query issue is caused by the fact that some parts' records are lazily loaded, thus it's one subsequent query for each fetched item for each accessed part.

With ContentQuery there is QueryHints to eagerly load part records with IHqlQuery (the query used in Projector filters) you could use its Join() method to join in (= eagerly load) tables. However this needs you to write code: creating a Projector filter provider that only joins in tables, then use this filter with the respective queries.

I don't know of any simpler option for eager loading with projector but it's something well worth exploring. Why don't you open an issue about this?

Comment: The problem is that the code to the second database isn't NHibernate like Orchard itself uses, but uses Entity Framework. The parts that get loaded execute (through a manager) loads of queries in Entity Framework. I'm now trying to build caching into it.

Is it possible using a filter to prevent loading anything else than the title part?

What would you have me report in the issue btw?

Comment: Only parts whose properties are accessed are loaded. Most of the time this means only parts are loaded that display something: hiding everything except Parts_Title with Placement.info should mostly solve the issue. I thought about creating an issue about eager-loading part records for Projector queries.

Comment: Should you hide them with placement.info even when they aren't visibly there?

Comment: Yes. If a driver is properly coded then if something is hidden from Placement.info most of the processing won't take place.